# create react app deploy to digitalocean problem with pm2

Tags: deployment, pm2

I am very new at this and I am following this tutorial (https://hackernoon.com/start-to-finish-deploying-a-react-app-on-digitalocean-bcfae9e6d01b) to practice deploying my standard created app via create-react-app in digitalocean.

While running [pm2 serve build] it shows:

```
pm2 serve build
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [static-page-server-8080](ids: 0)
[PM2] [static-page-server-8080](0) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
[PM2] Serving /home/carles/build on port 8080
```

But it nothing to see on the mentioned port. This is what I get when running [pm2 list]:

```
App name                │ id │ version │ mode │ pid │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem    │ user   │ watching │
├─────────────────────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ static-page-server-8080 │ 0  │ 3.3.1   │ fork │ N/A │ errored │ 0       │ 0      │ 0%  │ 0 B    │ carles │ disabled │
```

All worked fine until this point #3 of the tutorial. Any Idea how to make this work? I appreciate your help!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you follow these instructions: [server-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#static-server)

But, before of run your aplication in a server, do you need `built` it, running:

```
yarn build
```

or

```
npm run build
```

When the build is completed, it will create a folder with name `build` , then, do you will need inform to your server run in build folder. Then

1. Run `yarn build` or `npm run build`
2. `npm install -g serve`
3. `pm2 serve build`
4. `Access it: http://someip:8080`

In this case it will run your application from `build` and with port `8080`.
With this your application will works.